# Gitolite setup: unable to login with ssh key

Tags: ssh, centos, gitolite

I am trying to setup Gitlab on my server (Centos 6.3) and facing some problems with Gitolite setup.

I have created two users (as mentioned in guide :)). gitlab and git. Created ssh keys for gitlab and copied the public key (gitlab.pub) to git's home. And set it up with `gitolite setup -pk gitlab.pub`.

Now when I am trying to open ssh session from gitlab account it asks for password. Commands are as follows

```
ssh git@localhost
git@localhost's password:  #asks for password here
```

No errors or warnings. Copying of test repo fails with same problem. Can anyone help me to find the problem.

Guide I have used are
1. [Gitlab Installation](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/stable/doc/install/installation.md) (for ubuntu)
2. https://gist.github.com/4362544 (centos specific)

Comment: As provided in the guide, account for user git has no password set. ie. the account is disabled. I set the password and it started working. All credit to @favoretti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post a link to the guide? Maybe I can see which step you missed.

But in general you need to create your own key pair, for the user you're trying to ssh to git from and then put its public key to gitolite configuration.

From your guide, these are the steps that have to do with key auth:

```
# adduser --system --shell /bin/sh --comment 'git version control' --user-group --create-home --home-dir /home/git git
# adduser --shell /bin/bash --create-home --home-dir /home/gitlab gitlab
# su - gitlab
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
$ exit
# cp ~gitlab/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ~git/gitlab.pub
# chmod 0444 ~git/gitlab.pub
# su - git
$ git clone git://github.com/gitlabhq/gitolite ~/gitolite
$ echo -e "PATH=\$PATH:/home/git/bin\nexport PATH" >> ~/.profile
$ source ~/.profile
$ gitolite/src/gl-system-install
$ sed -i 's/0077/0007/g' share/gitolite/conf/example.gitolite.rc
$ gl-setup -q /home/git/gitlab.pub
$ exit
```

So, check if you have `~gitlab/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, check if you have `~git/gitlab.pub`.

Then, the key-only connection will work only from `gitlab` user, so make sure you're trying `ssh git@localhost`, which being logged in as user `gitlab`.

If that's what you're doing you can look in `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog` for a reason of key rejection. Also, verify that key-based authentication is enabled in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, if not - enable it and restart `sshd`.

Comment: Didn't get your second statement. I have created ssh keys with user `gitlab` and used them in user `git` (gitolite setup). Now I am trying connection from user `gitlab` at git@localhost (i.e. user `git`)

Comment: Yes, both files are in place. public key copied to authorize_keys of user git. and i am trying the connection from user `gitlab`

Comment: At least i should get some errors on why the key is not being accepted

Comment: Anything in the logs? messages or syslog, it should normally give a reason of rejection, most popular being either improper rights for your own key or for authorized_keys file.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not so good in linux, Where I can find those logs?

Comment: See the answer ;) The last paragraph :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21867/discussion-between-uday-sawant-and-favoretti)